# Classification List Comprehension Not Behaving as Expected

Tags: python

I have built a list comprehension that takes in a list of lists `[actual, predicted]` and then classifies the contained lists. I want to produce output lists that have 1 if the original element is > .1, -1 if the original output is < -.1 and 0 if the original element is < .1 and > -.1. For example `[[2, 0, -2],[0, 0, 0]]` would be mapped to `[[1,0,-1], [0,0,0]]`.

I am using this code to perform this:
`classified = [list(map(lambda x: 1 if x > .1 else (-1 if x < .1 else 0), i)) for i in inputs]`.

However, when my code should classify an element as 0, it classifies it as -1. For example `[-.15, -.05, 0]` is mapped to `[-1, -1, -1]` instead of `[-1, 0, 0]`. It does classify points that map to 1 and -1 correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-1 if x < .1 else 0` should be `-1 if x < -.1 else 0`